# How to calculate similarities between documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried to find the k-nearest neighbors of a given document in MongoDB.

My thought was calculating the similarities between documents and returning the highest k documents.

Data format:

```
{
    id:1024,
    class:'patient',
    name:'Alex',
    gender:'male',
    livingSuburb:'place A',
    nearestHospital:'hospital A'
    treatments:[
                {date:20170101,disease:'flu',medicine:['drug A','drug B']},
                ...]
}
```

My expected input is:

```
[{id:1024}]
```

I want to take all parameters into the calculation because I want to find k most similar patients and use their data to do the further research.

My expected output is:

```
[
    {id:1201,similarity:0.98},
    {id:1108,similarity:0.93},
    {id:0001,similarity:0.88},
    ...
]
```

I have about 100,000 documents in my collection.

Is it possible to implement this function using NodeJS+MongoDB?

Comment: Which are the parameters you are choosing to calculate the similarity?

Comment: Hi, I want to take all parameters into the calculation. Cheers. @israel.zinc

Comment: Well, than you can implement in any language you want. Just need to fetch data from mongo and do it. I would suggest scala/spark for it. Javascript is interpreted and so, it might slow-down your process.

Comment: I am now using Nodejs and MongoDB to built up a website, so I was thinking if I could fetch results from MongoDB. @israel.zinc

Comment: But do you think you can run your calculations in a reasonable time using nodejs?